# Wifi not working after reboot

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, broadcom

I am posting this thread after trying all the solutions provided in the forums but it does not work for me.

These are the step that I have taken:

1- installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (with all the updates)

> 2- wifi not working, so I run *sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source* ,reboot, then run  *sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source*

The Wifi started working, but when I reboot the computer it stops working again.

I added these to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf but still no luck:

-blacklist brcmsmac

-blacklist bcma

-blacklist ssb

-blacklist b43

what exactly am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `sudo modprobe wl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593848/254422

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

It's weird but it was a simple grub update.

"wl" was the driver that  worked for me after installing the *bcmwl-kernel-source*. the problem is that the installation modifies */boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-38-generic* so that the driver that would be detected after reboot would stay wl, however my OS was booting from */boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-24-generic* where it was detecting "bcma-pci" instead of "wl". to solve that problem I run a simple grub update so that my OS will be booting from the new *initrd.img-4.15.0-38-generic*.